Linux: GCC 9.3: linking against a dynamic library compiled with GCC 4.8
So, I have a proprietary library (not open source) that was compiled with Devtoolset-3 (GCC 4.8).  Currently, Devtoolset-3 is marked as EOL (end-of-life) for the target distro (CentOS 7).  So, installing it has been denied due to IT policies in my company (they install only versions with active support).  Under those IT policies, I have Devtoolset-9 in the Linux system, the oldest one that the IT support allows to install.
So, is there a way to compile with GCC 9.3 but linking against a library compiled with GCC 4.8?  I ask that because CMake says it finds the old library, however the CMakeCache.txt in the build directory has a series of *_NOTFOUND library configurations which, I suspect, are caused by failures to link during those little sanity tests CMake does.  These *_NOTFOUNDs, in turn, result in build failure.

Unless your newer tool chain explicitly lists compatibility with libraries built with the older one, I wouldn't rely on that working properly at all times - even if you do get it to compile and link.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html may contain information you need

One easy solution would be if you could get the library vendor to provide you with a new build of the library using your tool chain of choice. Have you checked if that's an option?

@JesperJuhl. Indeed.  They have newer versions of the offending library.  However, that would mean making changes to the legacy code (the API has changed since then).  I have to rule out the possibility to solve this by just linking before investing time and effort upgrading the client code.

@PauloCarvalho Maybe you could get them to provide a build of the older library using a newer tool chain? I would find it worth a few minutes to ask..

Just link with it. The linker has no idea what the version of the comnpiler is. If you have a problem specifically with CMake, solve the problem with CMake. That would involve looking at CMake logs I guess. The problem has nothing to do with the toolchain used to build your library.

@JesperJuhl You cannot even rely on things working properly if they are all built with the same compiler.

@n.m.couldbeanAI "You cannot even rely on things working properly if they are all built with the same compiler" - Right; but it does up the chances considerably

@JesperJuhl No it does not. I have bever ever in my life had a problem due to a broken promise of GCC backwards compatibility, but tons of problems due to plain old regular bugs.

@n.m.couldbeanAI You may not have, but I have. I've had weird crashes when linking with libraries compiled with old "almost ABI compatible" versions of libraries. It's a real concern and it can result in really hard to diagnose bugs, because it mostly works.

If your program is build with C++, you may need to use -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0, but other than that, there should be no special considerations.

@JesperJuhl We need a bit of quantitative analysis here. How many bugs duie to undocumented ABI incompatibilities you have encountered, as opposed to all other hard to diagnose bugs? I would also love to see a specific example.

@n.m Where did I say "undocumented"?

@JesperJuhl Nevermind, I just have misread your initial comment. It says "unless" but I somehow understood the opposite.

@JesperJuhl I totally agree.  I'm going to try that. The vendor is a multi-billionaire company that will very likely just tell me to upgrade my client code and use their latest version.

@PepijnKramer So, according to that page, a -fabi-version=2 flag in the compiler command suffices.  I'm going to try that and give feedback.

@JesperJuhl Vendor reply: "we are very sorry to hear that, but..." . Summary: they wont make a Devtoolset-9 build of their legacy libraries.  Thank you for your suggestion.

@PepijnKramer Unfortunatelly, passing -fabi-version-2 compiler flag didn't solve the issue.  I double-checked CMakeCache.txt, it's there.  But, no avail.  Thank you for sharing.

@n.m.couldbeanAI -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 didn't function as expected in this case, either isolated or combined with -fabi-version=2.  Thank you for the help.

I can only recommend looking at verbose CMake logs.

@n.m.couldbeanAI That's a good suggestion.  Thanks.
